# Как измерить время выполнения метода с помощью timeit Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть метод поиска подстроки в строке и нужно измерить время выполнения этого метода. Сейчас я измеряю так:

```
timeit.timeit('method(pattern, text)','from xxx import method', 'from __main__ import pattern')
```

Но это не работает - выходит ошибка "TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer". Как исправить ошибку и как сделать так, чтобы я мог вместо text мог использовать i-ый элемент массива?

```
timeit.timeit('method(pattern, text[i])', ...)
```

Comment: [Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1284110/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-timeit-python) дополненный и более понятный ответ.

Answer (score 3):

`timeit` по умолчанию выполняется в отдельном пространстве имён. Если вам нужно, чтобы в выражении использовались глобальные переменные, нужно задать параметр `globals`:

```
text=["a","b", "c"]
i=2
timeit.timeit("len(text[i])", globals=globals())
```

Если `globals` не задавать, будет ошибка `NameError: name 'text' is not defined`

Функция `timeit` возвращает суммарное время выполнения. Для того, чтобы узнать среднее время выполнения одной итерации, нужно разделить возвращаемое значение на число повторений:

```
text=["a","b", "c"]
i=2
n = 10000
timeit.timeit("len(text[i])", globals=globals(), number=n)/n
```

Результат `8.309150000013688e-08`

Comment: Спасибо, ваш вариант работает, но как то слишком долго, на тестовом примере я ищу "ABC" в строке "ABCDE" и timeit возвращает 9.34. Так и должно быть?

Comment: @kfcgenius функция `timeit` возвращает суммарное время. Нужно делить на число итераций. Я добавил в ответ.